# Electron Failed to load Module

Tags: angular, electron

When I try to load my Angular Project as an Electron app, I get the following error:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.**

I used this tutorial to create the application and now I'm trying to add some components. So my code is similar to the one supplied in the tutorial I just added the `Homecomponent` with `ng generate`.

https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-desktop-electron/

The solution that was given in the tutorials comment section isn't working for me or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced the same issue recently and after some research discovered this error is caused by Angular 8 not adding MIME types to Typescript files converted to js. If you `ng serve` and inspect the page, you'll notice the js scripts have a type of `"module"`, this confuses Electron. There are several workarounds, as discussed in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30835).

What worked for me was simply changing the `"target"` property in the `"compilerOptions"` of `tsconfig.json` to `"es5"`.

I hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: Saved me!  Thank you.

Comment: Saved my career! LOL :D Thanks Mate :DD

Answer (score 0):

In your "createWindow" function in your main.ts, do you see this configuration? :

```
webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true }
```

It should be present in your creation of the browser window using the command

```
new BrowserWindow({})
```

inside the brackets you would have you window size dimensions and it is also where the webPreferences should go.

The Strict MIME type error is most likely from your Electron build interpreting ES6 Javascript or typescript wrong.

So setting the nodeIntegration to true, should solve the problem

Comment: yes the first Line of it looks like this  
**win = new electron_1.BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true } });**

Comment: Ok. How are you trying to bring up the project?
ng serve
npm run electron

Comment: npm run electron 

i tried ng serve and it is possible to view the pages correctly with Localhost

Comment: in the "main.ts", in the "win.loadURL" section, there is a "pathname" reference to the index.html file. Does that file exist? The project needs to be build before being referenced. 

If the file is there, the reference to it in the "main.ts" file looks malformed i to me. Maybe try removing the first slash in the path

Comment: i can view all contents that i put in the index.html file but it doesnt load the components